# Java: Pattern.compile()

Tags: java, performance

Consider following piece of code

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)  
  Pattern p=Pattern.compile(someExpression);
```

Will this java code cause same pattern to compile 10 times or will it compile only once when i=0?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Answer (score 2):

The compilation will take place 10 times as each iteration of the loop, a new variable named `p` is declared within the heap. Then the pattern compilation will take place, in which `p` is set as the resultant of the compilation, a `Pattern` object.

`p` will reach its end of life once an iteration is over. This cycle repeats 10 times until the entire For loop is over.

Comment: Thus, if you do not want to change the pattern, declare it before the loop and hold it as long as need it.

Comment: Correct, if the pattern don't change and you are going to use it very often then you might want to declare it as a class variable to avoid recompilation.

Comment: Moreover, is can be declared as `static` class variable, since the `Pattern`is thread-safe

Comment: Pattern class does not keep track of previously compiled pattern? So that for each subsequent calls simply return the same obj.

Comment: @vis yep it does not. Refer to the Java documentation for `Pattern.Compile`, [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#compile(java.lang.String)). It does not mention anything along that line, hence you can safely conclude it does not.